# enable input text and disabled checkbox with price calculate automatically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I have a checkbox with input field quantity to calculate price automatically. Now it work fine if I check the checkbox option and input quantity.
I would like delete the checkbox and insert only input quantity with calculate price automatically.

```
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="option[<?php echo $pt; ?>][]" 
        value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>|1" id="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"
        price_prefix="<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?>" price="<?php printf("%.5f", $option_value['price_value_tax']); ?>" 
        onchange="calc_<?php echo $pt; ?>();"/>
    </div>


    <div>          
        <input type="text" name="" id="opt-qty-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" value="1" oninput="
        $('#option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>').val( <?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?> + '|' + Number($(this).attr('value')) );
        $('#option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>').attr('price', Number($(this).attr('price')) * Number($(this).attr('value')) );
        calc_<?php echo $pt; ?>();
        "size="4" price="<?php echo $option_value['price_value_tax']; ?>" style="width: 20px;" />
    </div>  

    <span id="total-<?php echo $pt; ?>">
```

Here the script

```
    function calc_<?php echo $pt; ?>() {

var price = 0;
$('#option-<?php echo $pt; ?> input:checked').each(function() {   
    if ($(this).attr('price_prefix') == '+') {
        price += Number($(this).attr('price'));
    } else if ($(this).attr('price_prefix') == '-') {
        price -= Number($(this).attr('price'));
    }
});
$('#total-<?php echo $pt; ?>').html( price_format_sign(price) );

}
```

How can work it only with input text (input quantity) and without checkbox input?

Comment: Looks like spaghetti !

Comment: Right now you are only calculating based on each checked checkbox -> `$('... input:checked').each()`. So now do you want to do every input, or are you still wanting to filter which inputs?

Comment: I want delete checkbox input but with price calculate automatically when I insert input text.

Comment: So you want to simpilfy it to something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/LxtFg/1/?

Comment: I'm sorry. I wrote wrong...because each input text (quantity) has a field price. The price calculate automatically will be : price*input quantity(field text).

Comment: so more like this - http://jsfiddle.net/LxtFg/2/?

Comment: Hi Sean, Thanks your help but it doesn't work me for.My problem isn't easy because my checkbox are options of products. It has many different tags (id, value, price, prefix, name, tax, etc....)and  different code to calculate price automatically.THank you again to spend your time for me.